# CSS failure when using INCLUDE Function

Tags: php, css

I downloaded a Template + CSS File for a Website that I'm Building, the template worked well until I tried to break it down and put every code in its own file (for easy modification and editing in the future).
So, when I cut the head part which included (Title + Meta Data .. etc ), and put it in its own file, and replaced it (for sure) with an `include()` function, I lost the CSS styles and returned to the basic & standard style (Black & white with no extra format .. etc)

Where did I Go wrong? Knowing that here is the include function that I've used:

```
<?php
include 'files/head.php';
?>
```

Comment: Open developer tools or firebug and see if code defined in head is loaded at all. Also - you may add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the beginning of your script and see if some errors are shown. Possibly include path is simply wrong.

Comment: You are not including the part where css file link is.

Comment: If the title and other meta data is being shown the problem will be due to relative paths for the CSS.  Try setting the full-path to the CSS to see if that helps resolve it for now e.g. http://www.mysite.com/files/style.css

Comment: my css file is in :
`C:\xampp\htdocs\test6\css\screen.css`
my head file is in :
`C:\xampp\htdocs\test6\files\head.php`
what should the path to css file be ? ( the INDEX is in :
`C:\xampp\htdocs\test6\index.php` )

Comment: It depends. What is an url when you open index.php? http://localhost/index.php or http://localhost/test6/index.php? Or maybe some other url?

Comment: it's : `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/test6/index.php`

Comment: Press Ctrl+U in browser and see source code shown. I bet you will find there full code of index.php (with include etc). Do you see that?

Comment: yes I see it , with the php INCLUDE function in RED .
`<?php
include 'files/head.php';
?>`

Comment: Yeah. Here is a problem. Answer will be shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an URL like `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/test6/index.php` PHP is NOT executed. You must run it with apache being involved. Currently you are opening your PHP script as a regular txt or html file - it is just passed to browser without processing.

In order to make `include` function work you must run it with apache. As you are using xamp, I think you should simply open it with URL like `http://localhost/test6/index.php` In this case, apache will get that request and pass it to PHP. PHP engine will interpret your PHP script and "replace" `include files/head.php` with a content of head.php.
If everything is Ok, after pressing Ctrl+U (or looking at HTML with Developer Tools or Firebug) you should see a content of head.php instead of `<?php include ....`

Please note that css files should be linked with relative URL like `css/screen.css`. Or absolute URL like `http://localhost/test6/css/screen.css`.  like  Search for relative and absolute URLs in google for more info.